# How to run multiple postman/newman collections in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, newman, postman-newman

I am trying to run multiple postman collections in a docker container. Since postman doesn't come with the feature to run a folder with multiple collections, I tried to run multiple commands in docker. Nothing worked.
This is my dockerfile.

```
FROM postman/newman_alpine33
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT["sh","-c"]
```

And this is my postman container in docker-compose.

```
postman:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-postman
    container_name: postmanTests
    command:
       run "https://www.getpostman.com/collections/1" --env-var "base_url=http://service:8080" && 
       run "https://www.getpostman.com/collections/2" --env-var "base_url=http://service:8080"
    volumes:
      - container-volume:/var/lib/postman
    depends_on:
      - service
```

I tried using the sh-c command, the bash -c command, but I got an error that -c is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ENTRYPOINT` line is causing problems.  It forces the entire command you might want to run to be packed into a single shell word.  Compose `command:` doesn't expect this, and I'd expect your container to try to execute the shell command `run` with no arguments.

One straightforward path here could be to just run multiple containers.  I'm looking at [the documentation for the `postman/newman_alpine33` image](https://hub.docker.com/r/postman/newman_alpine33) and it supports injecting the Postman data as a Docker mount of some sort.  Compose is a little better suited to long-running containers than short-lived tasks like this.  So I might run

```bash
docker run                                         \
  --rm                                             \ # clean up the container when done
  -v name_container-volume:/var/lib/postman        \
  --net name_default                               \ # attach to Compose network
  postman/newman_alpine33                          \ # the unmodified image
  --url "https://www.getpostman.com/collections/1" \ # newman options
  --env-var "base_url=http://service:8080"

docker run --rm --net name_default \
  -v name_container-volume:/var/lib/postman \
  postman/newman_alpine33 \
  --url "https://www.getpostman.com/collections/2" \
  --env-var "base_url=http://service:8080"
```

(You could use a shell script to reduce the repetitive options, or alternatively use `docker-compose run` if you can write a service definition based on this image.)

If you really want to do this in a single container, it's helpful to understand what the base image is actually doing with those command arguments.  The Docker Hub page links to a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman-docker) and you can in turn find the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman-docker/blob/develop/images/alpine33/Dockerfile) there.  That ends with the [line](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman-docker/blob/develop/images/alpine33/Dockerfile#L39)

```bash
ENTRYPOINT ["newman"]
```

so the `docker run` command part just supplies arguments to `newman`.  If you want to run multiple things in the same container, and orchestrate them using a shell, you need to replace this entrypoint, and you need to explicitly restate the `newman` command.

For this we could do everything in a Compose setup, and that makes some sense since the Postman collections are "data" and the URLs are environment-specific.  Note here that we override the `entrypoint:` at run time, and its value has exactly three items, `sh`, `-c`, and the extended command to be run packed into a single string.

```yaml
services:
  postman:
    image: postman/newman_alpine33         # do not build: a custom image
    volumes:
      - container-volume:/var/lib/postman
      - .:/etc/newman                      # inject the collections
    entrypoint:                            # override `newman` in image
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - >-
          newman 
            --url "https://www.getpostman.com/collections/1"
            --env-var "base_url=http://service:8080"
          && newman
            --url "https://www.getpostman.com/collections/1"
            --env-var "base_url=http://service:8080"
    depends_on:
      - service
```

(The `>-` syntax creates a YAML [block scalar](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#81-block-scalar-styles); the text below it is a single string.  `>` converts all newlines within the string to spaces and `-` removes leading and trailing newlines.  I feel like I see this specific construction somewhat regularly in a Kubernetes context.)